# Load the local file rather than the remote url

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

Is possible load the local file rather than the remote url? I tried to write the Url property within the event "Navigating" but the property is read-only, I need to do to change the Url?

```
Remote Url: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
Local File: file:///D:/js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js
```

I need to do this dynamically, the person will open the application and navigate through several different sites of your choice, if one of these sites have the jquery file, the local charge is made, it aims to optimize the page loading speed and correct other syntax errors and undefined functions for I can fix the place javascript file.

The jquery is just an example to understand and perhaps help me, the same logic is used in different files.

Comment: Your question might be easier to answer if it had a little more detail, like what you mean by `load`. Can you copy your local `jquery.js` file into a directory in your website, like `Content` then refer to it by its local URL, like `/Content/jquery.js`?

Comment: I edited my comment and said my purpose more clearly, the ideal is to load site files if they exist to optimize the load time and also correct syntax JS files for IE (7 and 8, mostly) cause errors with some scripts while in the other browsers the same code runs smoothly.